# NetworkManager is failing to switch AP: Connection Activation Failed

Tags: networking, network-interface, networkmanager, access-point

I would like to switch which AP an iot device is connected to based on some external logic.  My AP switching script looked like this:

```
function switch_ap() {
  current_connection=$(nmcli conn show --active | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f1)
  nmcli conn down $current_connection
  if test "$current_connection" = "home_ap"; then
    nmcli conn up iot_ap
  else
    nmcli conn up home_ap
  fi
  new_connection=$(nmcli conn show --active | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f1)
  echo "was connected to $current_connection, now connected to connection: $(nmcli conn show --active | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f1) ssid: $(iwgetid wlan0 -r)"
}
```

Sometimes this works, but not reliably.  More often I get an error:

```
Connection 'home_ap' successfully deactivated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/66)
Error: Connection activation failed: The base network connection was interrupted
Hint: use 'journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=dcbf7f18-1e26-41bb-a874-c1ce6718dbf2 + NM_DEVICE=wlan0' to get more details.
```

I don't see the problem from running the `journalctl` command, but I'll share the output at the bottom of this post in case someone else is better at parsing those logs.

My hack-fix is this function:

```
function switch_ap() {
  current_connection=$(nmcli conn show --active | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f1)
  nmcli conn down $current_connection
  if test "$current_connection" = "home_ap"; then
    mv /etc/nm_connections/iot_ap.nmconnection /opt/nm_connections/
    mv /opt/home_ap.nmconnection /etc/nm_connections/
    nmcli conn up iot_ap
  else
    mv /etc/nm_connections/home_ap.nmconnection /opt/nm_connections/
    mv /opt/nm_connections/iot_ap.nmconnection /etc/nm_connections/
    nmcli conn up home_ap
  fi
  new_connection=$(nmcli conn show --active | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f1)
  echo "was connected to $current_connection, now connected to connection: $(nmcli conn show --active | tail -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f1) ssid: $(iwgetid wlan0 -r)"
}
```

This one seems to work reliably, but now I won't automatically switch if I lose connection to the connected ap, and it is a hack.  I now also see these warnings more frequently:

```
(process:12734): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 06:05:20.284: ../../gio/gdbusobjectmanagerclient.c:1589: Processing InterfaceRemoved signal for path /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP4Config/35 but no object proxy exists

(process:12734): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 06:05:20.293: ../../gio/gdbusobjectmanagerclient.c:1589: Processing InterfaceRemoved signal for path /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/IP6Config/35 but no object proxy exists

(process:12734): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 06:05:20.591: ../../gio/gdbusobjectmanagerclient.c:1589: Processing InterfaceRemoved signal for path /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/35 but no object proxy exists
```

Any ideas to make my AP switching more reliable?

Here are the logs from the `journalctl` command:

```
Connection 'iot_ap' successfully deactivated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/33)
Connection successfully activated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/37)
Apr 21 09:03:08 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481388.5536] device (wlan0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 09:03:08 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481388.5912] device (wlan0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 09:03:08 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481388.5946] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'home_ap' has security, but secrets are required.
Apr 21 09:03:08 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481388.5948] device (wlan0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 09:03:08 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481388.6554] device (wlan0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 09:03:08 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481388.6598] device (wlan0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 09:03:08 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481388.6634] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'home_ap' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Apr 21 09:03:08 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481388.9623] device (wlan0): disconnecting for new activation request.
Apr 21 09:03:08 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481388.9626] device (wlan0): state change: config -> deactivating (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 09:03:08 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481388.9781] device (wlan0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 09:03:09 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481389.0102] device (wlan0): Activation: starting connection 'iot_ap' (b109024a-84b9-46b7-a810-2d2472676c7f)
Apr 21 09:03:09 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481389.0413] device (wlan0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 09:03:09 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481389.0750] device (wlan0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 09:03:09 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481389.0810] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'iot_ap' has security, but secrets are required.
Apr 21 09:03:09 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481389.0819] device (wlan0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 09:03:09 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481389.0867] sup-iface[0x3a2201c0,wlan0]: wps: type pbc start...
Apr 21 09:03:09 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481389.8388] device (wlan0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 09:03:09 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481389.8922] device (wlan0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 09:03:09 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481389.9060] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'iot_ap' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Apr 21 09:03:09 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481389.9470] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Apr 21 09:03:10 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481390.4927] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> associating
Apr 21 09:03:10 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481390.5582] device (wlan0): disconnecting for new activation request.
Apr 21 09:03:10 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481390.5584] device (wlan0): state change: config -> deactivating (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 09:03:10 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481390.5645] device (wlan0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'new-activation', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 09:03:10 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481390.5915] device (wlan0): Activation: starting connection 'home_ap' (dcbf7f18-1e26-41bb-a874-c1ce6718dbf2)
Apr 21 09:03:10 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481390.6027] device (wlan0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 09:03:10 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481390.6214] device (wlan0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 09:03:10 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481390.6386] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'home_ap' has security, but secrets are required.
Apr 21 09:03:10 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481390.6388] device (wlan0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 09:03:10 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <warn>  [1587481390.6968] sup-iface[0x3a2201c0,wlan0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Apr 21 09:03:10 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481390.6974] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Apr 21 09:03:10 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481390.6983] device (wlan0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 09:03:10 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481390.7046] device (wlan0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 09:03:10 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481390.7357] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'home_ap' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Apr 21 09:03:10 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481390.7815] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> associated
Apr 21 09:03:10 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <warn>  [1587481390.7900] sup-iface[0x3a2201c0,wlan0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Apr 21 09:03:11 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481391.0013] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associated -> disconnected
Apr 21 09:03:11 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481391.6999] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> associating
Apr 21 09:03:11 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481391.7886] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Apr 21 09:03:11 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481391.8417] device (wlan0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Apr 21 09:03:11 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481391.8419] device (wlan0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "TheHome"
Apr 21 09:03:11 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481391.8624] device (wlan0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 09:03:11 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481391.8689] dhcp4 (wlan0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Apr 21 09:03:11 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481391.8964] dhcp4 (wlan0): dhclient started with pid 22677
Apr 21 09:03:12 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481392.2540] dhcp4 (wlan0):   address 192.168.1.61
Apr 21 09:03:12 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481392.2542] dhcp4 (wlan0):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Apr 21 09:03:12 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481392.2543] dhcp4 (wlan0):   gateway 192.168.1.1
Apr 21 09:03:12 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481392.2546] dhcp4 (wlan0):   lease time 10806
Apr 21 09:03:12 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481392.2547] dhcp4 (wlan0):   nameserver '75.75.75.75'
Apr 21 09:03:12 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481392.2548] dhcp4 (wlan0):   nameserver '75.75.76.76'
Apr 21 09:03:12 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481392.2550] dhcp4 (wlan0): state changed unknown -> bound
Apr 21 09:03:12 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481392.2964] device (wlan0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 09:03:12 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481392.3029] device (wlan0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 09:03:12 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481392.3051] device (wlan0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Apr 21 09:03:12 DEVICE-072059 NetworkManager[249]: <info>  [1587481392.4438] device (wlan0): Activation: successful, device activated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network manager is made to mange networks, it has logic to switch networks based on availability. when you run the first script and take it down, the network manager daemon probably notices and connects to whatever is the default that’s available.

The second one you’re moving the files that tell network manager which wifi access points it should connect to. So when it has the home file it’ll only ever be able to connect to home because that’s the only network it knows about. When it has the iot file it’ll only be able to connect to iot.

It won’t switch because network manager doesn’t know the other exists. The best way to fix your issue would be to set the priority for the SSIDs in network manager or to use “nmcli device wifi connect ” which should work to connect to a different SSID without taking it down. If not that command the nmcli man pages should be useful figuring out how.

Comment: I was previously running:
`# nmcli dev wifi connect <ssid> password <password> ifname wlan0`, but I kept getting:
`Error: Connection activation failed: (10) 802.1X supplicant failed.`
It seemed to work better by telling it to take the connection down then to put a connection up.

Comment: Is there a way to change the priority from nmcli, that sounds promising - I'll take a look at the man pages and report if I find a solution

Comment: Looks like I can set priority like this: `nmcli c mod <con_name> connection.autoconnect-priority <X>`, I can also tell it to not to autoconnect: `nmcli c mod <con_name> connection.autoconnect no`

Comment: Glad you figured it out!